# Convert NSString to different Charset

Tags: ios, cocoa, character-encoding, nsstring

We are developing a simple usenet reader for iOS5 implementing the NNTP protocol.

Unfortunately we have some problem with the encoding: A header may look like:

```
Subject: Re: [GA] =?ISO-8859-15?Q?Pr=FCfungsmodus?= 
Date: 22 Apr 2012 22:50:38 +0200
```

Is there some simple way in Objective-C to convert a NSString containing `=?ISO-8859-15?Q?Pr=FCfungsmodus?=`  to "`Prüfungsmodus`"?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Hm. I'm not sure if I got this right:
You meant something like:

```
NSRange range = [input rangeOfString:@"=?"];
NSRange range2 = [input rangeOfString:@"?="];

NSString *string_to_decode = [input substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location, range2.location-(range.location-2))];


NSData *data = [string_to_decode dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *converted = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)];
```

Because that's not working..

**EDIT2**
Trying to convert the raw bytes:

```
uint8_t buffer[1024];
iStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

No matter which encoding I choose here the `Subject:` Field will always look the same (except for japanese etc encoding...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this yourself from first principles then in outline:

- Read the bytes from the network
- Determine the ranges of each run in a particular encoding - in your example you're looking for =?...?= sections [this looks like MIME word encoding] - for each range you need byte pointer, length, encoding [which may be both a character set and a separate encoding style, here it looks like ISO-8859-15 with Q-encoding]
- create an `NSString` for each using `- (id)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`
- concatenate
- you also need to deal with other escape sequences in the input, e.g. when the input contains a literal `=?`

For details on MIME look at Wikipedia.

*[Edit: added notes on MIME.]*

Comment: @dominik - your edit just encodes and decodes using the same char set... Start with the *raw bytes* read from the network (which you probably have as an `NSData` - you get a pointer to the raw bytes and number of bytes from that), don't convert them to a string. Now determine each run of bytes in a particular encoding and convert that run of bytes to a string, then concatenate the resulting strings to produce the final result.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I tried that too, using every single Encoding available. The result will stay the same tough. (See EDIT2)..

Comment: @dominik - you are trying to convert the whole line at once, you need to split it up into runs "Subject: Re: [GA] " and "Pr=FCfungsmodus" - the latter is in ISO-8859-15 using Q-encoding. This is MIME word-encoding, so you need to decode the Q-encoding and then interpret the bytes as ISO-8859-15. You might also come across B-encoding, which is base 64. Look up MIME on Wikipedia. There are at least commercial MIME decoders for Objective-C, Google is your friend.

Comment: Ok now I see what you meant. Thanks for your help. I'll try to implement this!